# Pycairo C API linker errors

Tags: python, c, cairo, pycairo

I am trying to include the pycairo C API in a C application.

I include the pycairo header:

```
#include Pycairo.h
```

and this is on my include path. But I get a load of linking errors (LNK2019), along the lines of `undefined external reference __imp__cairo`...

I understand that the `__imp__` indicates it is looking for a shared library (rather than static). I have both cairo.dll and _cairo.pyd on my library path.
Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: Can you include the command you are using to compile this?

Comment: You do actually *link* with the library? The linker will not find the libraries of its own.

Comment: app is being built using the gyp system. I have added pycairo.h and both the dll and pyd to the relevant sections of the gyp file (I believe)...